# eText.setError() Fatal error

Tags: android, validation, fatal-error

After submit on button i get errors

```
04-30 11:08:19.990 14339-14339/hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker E/AndroidRuntime:     FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker.RegisterActivity.isEmpty(RegisterActivity.java:72)
                                                                            at hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker.RegisterActivity.registerOnclick(RegisterActivity.java:58)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText username;
EditText password;
EditText passwordAgain;
Spinner accountTypeSpinner;
Button registerButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Fetch registerbutton by id
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    //Fetch username, password,passwordAgain , accountTypeSpinner  by id
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    EditText passwordAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordAgain);
    Spinner accountTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerSpinner);
}

public void registerOnclick(View v){



    //Get text from objects
    String strUsername  = username.getText().toString();
    String strPassword  = password.getText().toString();
    String strPassowrdAgain = passwordAgain.getText().toString();
    String accounttype =  accountTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(isEmpty(strUsername,strPassword,strPassowrdAgain) == false){
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}//End of registerOnclick

public Boolean isEmpty(String strUsername, String strPassword, String strPassowrdAgain){
    Boolean isThereEmptyFields = false;


    if (strUsername.length() ==  0) {
        Log.d("test", "before set error");
        username.setError("First name is required!");
        Log.d("test", "after set error");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }
    if (strPassword.length() ==  0) {
        password.setError("First name is required!");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }
    if (strPassowrdAgain.length() ==  0) {
        passwordAgain.setError("First name is required!");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }

    return isThereEmptyFields;
}
```

}

Method setError() causes fatal exception ..If i use setError() inside function registerOnclick(View v) it works well but i need to create new function isEmpty()

Comment: I can't see `username` inside `isEmpty()` declared. Is it class scope property or what? Can you provide full class code?

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky updated

Comment: move `EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    EditText passwordAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordAgain);`
to the `onCreate()` section so they are initialized before referenced.

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky same problem

Comment: update with new code?

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky updated

Comment: remove type definitions before setting values. like this
`username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    passwordAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordAgain);`
else you create local variables with similar names.

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky solved. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
 Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
 //Fetch username, password,passwordAgain , accountTypeSpinner  by id
 username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
 password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
 passwordAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordAgain);
 accountTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerSpinner);
}

public void registerOnclick(View v){

String strUsername  = username.getText().toString();
String strPassword  = password.getText().toString();
String strPassowrdAgain = passwordAgain.getText().toString();
String accounttype =  accountTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(!isEmpty(strUsername,strPassword,strPassowrdAgain)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "this is text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}  }
```

you used if condition to check boolean in wrong format

use

```
 if(!isEmpty(strUsername,strPassword,strPassowrdAgain))
```

instead of

```
 if(isEmpty(strUsername,strPassword,strPassowrdAgain) == false)
```

Comment: error happen java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker.RegisterActivity.isEmpty

Comment: i normally use your way but that is not cause of the problem

Comment: change  registerOnclick(View v)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText username;
EditText password;
EditText passwordAgain;
Spinner accountTypeSpinner;
Button registerButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Fetch registerbutton by id
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    //Fetch username, password,passwordAgain , accountTypeSpinner  by id
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    EditText passwordAgain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordAgain);
    Spinner accountTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerSpinner);
}

public void registerOnclick(View v){



    //Get text from objects
    String strUsername  = username.getText().toString();
    String strPassword  = password.getText().toString();
    String strPassowrdAgain = passwordAgain.getText().toString();
    String accounttype =  accountTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(isEmpty(strUsername,strPassword,strPassowrdAgain) == false){
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}//End of registerOnclick

public Boolean isEmpty(String strUsername, String strPassword, String strPassowrdAgain){
    Boolean isThereEmptyFields = false;


    if (strUsername.length() ==  0) {
        Log.d("test", "before set error");
        username.setError("First name is required!");
        Log.d("test", "after set error");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }
    if (strPassword.length() ==  0) {
        password.setError("First name is required!");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }
    if (strPassowrdAgain.length() ==  0) {
        passwordAgain.setError("First name is required!");
        isThereEmptyFields =true;
    }

    return isThereEmptyFields;
}
```

}

Comment: Then i get new fatal error before i register activity is loaded FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker/hr.tosapinaetfos.quizmaker.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i want to see full Activity class code because the error your are showing is not in this code